# Does the integral converge

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to prove that the following integral doesn't converge? 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln^4x + \ln^2x)\ln^2(1-x^{1/3})^2(x + \sqrt{x} + 1)}dx$$

I suppose it doesn't converge because of quick growth rate of function at $x = 0$, but I can't prove that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $0$ is not the problem for convergence. Consider what's happening at $1$ instead.